# Use Hooked-Web3-Provider and Lightwallet on android app?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, truffle, eth-lightwallet

I'm trying to make a demo app where I can make an account through the app and store the private key. and simply send a signed transaction and from the app to a hosted blockchain on my computer

any tips on how to start? or is it possible? using web3 provider and ligthwallet?

Comment: Not sure, what have you tried yet?

Comment: I'm trying to implement web3 in an app using a wrapper first

Answer (score 1):

LightWallet is a HD wallet that can store your private keys encrypted in the browser to allow you to run Ethereum dapps even if you're not running a local Ethereum node. It uses BIP32 and BIP39 to generate an HD tree of addresses from a randomly generated 12-word seed.

LightWallet is primarily intended to be a signing provider for the Hooked Web3 provider through the keystore module. This allows you to have full control over your private keys while still connecting to a remote node to relay signed transactions. Moreover, the txutils functions can be used to construct transactions when offline, for use in e.g. air-gapped coldwallet implementations.

Comment: you copy pasted smh

Comment: what exactly did you want? Yes its possible using hooked web3 and lightwallet. Thats what they are for.